# ios read content from private network address

Tags: objective-c, ios, file-io, network-protocols

I need to read a file that come for example:

```
\\192.168.0.1\Folder\Readme.txt
```

how can I read this file from my app into the iPhone

Comment: I wish made the same thing like in windows you open a \\ip path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *pathToTextFile;
NSError  *readError;
NSString *fileData = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:pathToTextFile
                               encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                               error:*readError]

 NSLog(@"here is your file as string = %@",fileData);
```

Comment: simply this? and the pathToTextFile will be \\192.168.0.1\Folder\Readme.txt ??

Comment: Give it a try ;)
smb://server-name/folder-name/document.
I assume in your case : smb://192.168.0.1/Folder/Readme.txt

But as other stated, I am not sure iOS support SMB directly. how about putting it on your local webserver (Apache or alike)

Answer (score 1):

I think in this case you can use a library like ASIHTTP. [Link](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/)

It should be possible to download the file into a NSString object, and then store this object into a file.

```
[nsStringObject writeToFile:pathToFile atomically:YES encoding:stringEncoding error:errorHandler];
```

Comment: ASIHTTP is well... HTTP library, he needs to access his file via SMB protocol.

Answer (score 1):

As you suggest in your question, you need to access your file over SMB protocol (samba or windows share). I don't think iOS supports smb out of the box, however, i stumbled across [tango library on github](https://github.com/38leinaD/tango) some time ago. The library claims to be a SMB/CIFS implementation for iOS, so i guess you might give it a try.